# Problema modificando la página del carrito de Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy intentando modificar la tabla "total" que se muestra en la página del carrito, a través de su template `woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php`

El subtotal del carrito lo devuelve una función llamada `wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html()` y es un string formado por el precio total con dos decimales acompañado del símbolo de la divisa, en mi caso "€". Lo que quería hacer es quitarle el símbolo para poder operar posteriormente con el total. El problema viene que al intentar quitar el símbolo "€" con un `str_replace` éste sigue mostrándose como si nada.

Este es el código exacto que he utilizado:

```
$sub=wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html();
echo $sub;  //50,00€
$sub=str_replace('€', '', $sub);
echo $sub;  //50,00€
```

Al hacer un `var_dump()` a la variable `$sub` obtengo esto:

```
var_dump($sub);  //string(39) "50,00€"
```

También tengo los errores PHP activados y no devuelve ninguno.

¿Qué puede estar saliendo mal?

Comment: Intenta hacer el replace con un array..: `$symbols = array( '€');` y luego
`$sub= str_replace($symbols, '', $sub);` Si no es eso es probable que sea tema de codificación `UTF`

Comment: @MiquelColl Gracias por tu aporte, he probado lo que comentas y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, también he probado a pasar la cadena a utf8 antes de intentar quitar el símbolo y no hay cambios.

Comment: Hola @Hechi, has probado el `formatter`?

Comment: @MiquelCol Estoy haciendo unas cuantas pruebas pero sin mucho éxito. Voy a probar a buscar la función de Woocomerce que concatena la cantidad y el símbolo para ver cómo lo hace exactamente. Tu solución es bastante razonable y me parecía interesante, pero no parece funcionarme en éste caso, muchas gracias por los aportes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando un poco más el por qué he visto que todos los símbolos de dinero (`€`,`$`,etc...) se codifican un poco distinto. He encontrado muchas posibles soluciones pero parece que [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5140046/1468942) es la mejor utilizando la función [`parseCurrency`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php):

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('es_ES', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($formatter->parseCurrency($sub, $curr));
```

Otra opción menos fina (en caso de que la anterior falle) es hacerlo a saco con Regex:

```
$int = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $sub); 
echo $int;
```

Esto lo que hace es básicamente extraer todos los carácteres numéricos y no hacer caso del resto.

Cómo indica [Hechi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6974/hechi) en los comentarios, con `PHP 7` el `ereg_replace` está obsoleta con lo que la respuesta es con `preg_replace`:

```
$int = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]*/', "", $sub);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, había probado antes con `ereg_replace` pero lo había descartado ya que está obsoleto en PHP 7, sustituyéndolo por `preg_replace` y adecuando los parámetros para que también conserve la coma me ha funcionado de maravilla. Al final la expresión ha quedado tal que así:

    `$int = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]*/', "", $sub); `

 Gracias por iluminarme el camino, has sido de mucha ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma:

```
$sub = wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html();
echo $sub;  //50,00€
$precio = str_replace("€", "", $sub);
$precio = str_replace("&euro;", "", $precio);
echo $precio;
```

En php no es lo mismo utilizar `""` que `''`, puede que sea ese el problema

Prueba también a copiar exactamente el caracter que tienes en el echo, por si acaso, a mi a veces me ha pasado que no es mismo que el que se añade por teclado

Comment: Ninguna de las dos cosas que me comentas son el problema, para este caso concreto las comillas simples y las dobles tienen la misma función. Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, añadiendo mas posibles soluciones